# Function to translate input in one form to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a problem with translation of input from the .txt file (listed below) where first line (A, B) gives us information about:

**A:** number of nodes (unique numbers in file),

**B:** number of connections between given nodes (ex. 1-0, 0-1):

and the rest lines, are showing connections between given nodes.

So i want to translate below input:

**3 2**
**0 1**
**1 2**

into something like this:

```
{ 0 : [1],   
  1 : [2], 
  2 : [],  
   }
```

if given node (number) have no further connections (childs) its pair is **2 : []**

Another example, but with cycle:

**2 2**
**1 0**
**0 1**

```
{ 1 : [0],
  0 : [1], 
   }
```

Thanks for help in advance :)

P.S.

Got a code in js however i dont know how to translate it, and in addition it doesn't pair childless node with **[]**:

```
const USER_INPUT = "2 2\n1 0\n0 1";

function getInputLines(input) {
  const LINE_SEPARATOR = '\n';
  return input.split(LINE_SEPARATOR);
}

function getLineElements(line) {
  const ELEM_SEPARATOR = ' ';
  return line.split(ELEM_SEPARATOR)
}
```

P.S.S

python code for cycle searching in given graph:

```
def cycle_exists(G):                     
color = { u : "white" for u in G  }  
found_cycle = [False]                 

    if color[u] == "white":
        dfs_visit(G, u, color, found_cycle)
    if found_cycle[0]:
        break
return found_cycle[0]

def dfs_visit(G, u, color, found_cycle):
if found_cycle[0]:                          
    return
color[u] = "gray"                           
for v in G[u]:                               
    if color[v] == "gray":                     
        found_cycle[0] = True       
        return
    if color[v] == "white":                    
        dfs_visit(G, v, color, found_cycle)
color[u] = "black"
```

and the input is:

```
graph = { 1 : [0], 
          0 : []    
            }
```

Example:

**>>** cycle_exists(graph)

**>>** False

Comment: It's graphs so for example input for my script is:

graph_1 = { 0 : [1],
1 : [2], 
2 : [],
}

it means that node 0 have connection (child) 1, where 1 have connection (child) 2, however 2 does not have any childs (childless).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code to do what you want. This code also correctly handles the first example you gave before you edited your question: if a node has connections to more than one other node, all those other nodes are in the list. This assumes that the nodes have ids that are consecutive nonnegative integers starting with zero, as in all your examples.

```
USER_INPUT1 = "3 2\n0 1\n1 2\n"
USER_INPUT2 = "2 2\n1 0\n0 1"
USER_INPUT3 = "3 3\n1 0\n0 1\n1 2"

def input_to_graph_dict(input_string):
    # Get overall input information
    input_lines = input_string.strip().split('\n')
    num_nodes, num_connections = map(int, input_lines[0].split(' '))
    # Set up dictionary with all nodes but no connections
    graph_dict = {node_id: [] for node_id in range(num_nodes)}
    # Add connections to dictionary
    for connection in input_lines[1:]:
        from_id, to_id = map(int, connection.split(' '))
        graph_dict[from_id].append(to_id)
    # Done!
    return graph_dict

print(input_to_graph_dict(USER_INPUT1))
print(input_to_graph_dict(USER_INPUT2))
print(input_to_graph_dict(USER_INPUT3))
```

The printout from that is

```
{0: [1], 1: [2], 2: []}
{0: [1], 1: [0]}
{0: [1], 1: [0, 2], 2: []}
```

which is what you wanted, with the entries perhaps in a different order than in the examples you gave, which is the nature of a dictionary.

Comment: Wow, really big thanks!! It works right now :D Thank You very very much !